# Object is missing geometry in edit mode

Tags: mesh

One of my objects is using an array modifier but when I go into edit mode it seems like there is a small percentage of the mesh that should be there [Blender File](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1u1XCAQUcQmpnyyCv5H6HStBYkA3Ptz_7/view?usp=sharing). Any help would be appreciated.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You've hidden a part of your mesh in *Edit* mode, press <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>H</kbd> to unhide

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to the whimsically wroughtable world of modifiers! Modifiers are a “Procedural effect“ which means once they are programmed, they don’t require any user input. What that may not clearly but does implicitly mean is that the modifier operates on top of existing geometry, can be adjusted at any time, and until/unless it is applied it makes no permanent changes. This is why the armature modifier is useful: it does not permanently deform the mesh to the armature (unless it is applied), but rather performs it “at the last minute“ as it were, so you can still make changes to the character and do other practical things.

Comment: Note if you click on the downward facing triangle icon and on the square icon on the left of each modifier header, you will be able to preview its effect in edit mode