# Can’t Select Faces Inside Cylinder

Tags: faces

[image]

I’m very new to blender, this is the second tutorial I’m trying to follow (Ducky 3D’s environment tutorial). I’m trying to make the inside of the ring emissive but I can only select the outside faces. I tried remaking the cylinder thinking I made a mistake but it had the same issue, and wouldn’t let me select the inside faces.
I did try selecting the Interior Faces in the Select All By Trait but it didn't work either.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Object is missing geometry in edit mode](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/231190/object-is-missing-geometry-in-edit-mode)

Answer (score 4):

The inner faces are not real: they are being generated by the modifier. The idea of modifiers is that they are a “Procedural effect” that is, they follow a formula, and thus can run on top of the existing geometry, constantly virtually being the last thing you did. If you want to adjust a modifier, you can do it at any time. If one should want to adjust actual changes one made to the mesh, one would have to undo until they found the correct operation, and all the following work would be lost.

Comment: is there a way then to add thickness to the cylinder without a modifier? The tutorial I used was from 2 years ago, maybe in an update since then is there a way to make a cylinder like that with faces I can assign emission too?

Comment: @SynthwaveSuccubus Yes, the solidify modifier has a solidify operator counterpart, or you could just apply the modifier. Applying the modifier runs it permanently as an operator and deletes it.

Comment: The Solidify modifier is what I used in the image above but it doesn't leave me any faces to grab, but it worked in the tutorial.

Comment: @SynthwaveSuccubus Apply the modifier. I think it’s in a pull down in the modifier’s header

Comment: Thank you! Going off a tutorial using an older version of Blender, things have been moved around a bit since then so I had no idea where to find it lol Thanks again!

Comment: I will say as an afterthought that you can set the solidify modifier to use different materials for the solidified part than for the original. And, you’re welcome. PTLJ

Comment: you can also press Alt E > Extrude Faces Along Normals

Answer (score 1):

As @TheLabCat has said, you can't edit the faces generated by an un-applied modifier, because they don't exist, at edit time. However, you can assign materials to them. The *Solidify* and *Bevel* modifiers both have panels that allow you to set the material index for generated faces:

[image]

Sou you can have separate materials for inner, outer, rim, and bevel, if you want to:

[image]

...

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem in Blender 3.3, so I imported the project into Blender 2.8, applied the *Solidify* modifier, saved it and reopened it in Blender 3.3 and it worked.