# How to draw edge using an object

Tags: modeling, faces, edges, knife-tool

is there a way to add an edge like a knife tool, but using an object to follow its shape? I'm having a hard time using the knife tool since it doesn't give me accurate results like curvature when cutting, and it's a pain in the ass to draw the knife tool manually. The following images below represents on what I want to happen using the boolean modifier by subtracting it, however I want the faces to be still intact instead of erasing/deleting those faces, basically just draw the shape of the hole by edges while the faces are still there.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. It’s the “Intersect (Knife)” operator (as opposed to the “Intersect (Boolean)” operator).

[The blender Docs page on the Intersect (Knife) operator](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/meshes/editing/face/intersect_knife.html?highlight=intersect%20knife)

[Previous post explaining difference between modifiers and operators](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/231191/73575)

Comment: It worked, thank you!

Comment: @rhodtan012 praise The Lord!